# Why I'm getting empty request when i post data to the controller using ajax in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Hello guys i'm trying to post data to the controller using ajax in laravel but it is giving me empty request in the controller although the data i'm sending is already showing when i do `console.log(name)`

This is my form

```
<form action="" method="POST">
 <div class="row mb-3 align-items-end">
  <div class="col">
<label class="form-label">Permission Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder=" Enter a Permission name">
  </div>
  </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn me-auto" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
 <button type="button" class="add_per btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

And this is the ajax code

```
<script>
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.add_per', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var name = $('#name').val();
            console.log(name)
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                url: "{{route('admin.permissions.store')}}",
                data: {
                    name:name
                },
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status === true) {
                        $('#success_msg').show();

                    }
                },
                error: function (reject) {
                    alert("Error occurred !");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I've never worked with Laravel, but in my experience, data posted via AJAX won't be available in `$_POST` and you'd instead need to access it using something like `$postData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input",true))`

Comment: @outlaw — No. The code in the question will not encode the data as JSON.

Comment: Still, @outlaw laravel has a `Request` class, so you must use `$request->input('name')` instead of that crazy old PHP code to get the input... this is a framework, imagine Symfony doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> processData: false,
> ```

You told jQuery not to process the object you pass to `data` so it isn't being encoded in a way that allows it to be sent in the HTTP request.

> ```
> contentType: false,
> ```

You also told it not to set the content-type to the format it encoded the data to (which doesn't make a difference given the above, but would if you fixed the first problem).

> ```
> enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
> ```

jQuery doesn't accept an `enctype` property on the options object, but if it did it would be a for `contentType`. `multipart/form-data` is an encoding generally used for requests that include files; jQuery can't encode data using that format.

Comment: I put processData because i was giving me an error without is but now it's not i don't know why but yes it was the reason for my problem thanks,,